# My computer says i am running ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 16.10

```
maxaroth@maxaroth-PC:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Zesty Zapus (development branch)
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty
maxaroth@maxaroth-PC:~$
```

No idea why it says this but i would like a little insight on why please
i should be running 16.10

Comment: It would appear that you've installed 17.04 and not 16.10. Or you installed 16.10 and then did an upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

You may be running 16.10 but you have at least one package installed that comes from 17.04. `lsb_release` shows the content of `/etc/lsb-release` which is provided by package `base-files` and it shows you Ubuntu version. You can do the following command to better understand where it comes from:

```
apt-cache policy base-files
```

(`apt-cache show base-files` may provide some hints too)