# lsb_release in Xubuntu showing 17.04 Zesty Zapus (development branch)

Tags: xubuntu, 16.10

I installed Xubuntu 16.10 a month ago. Now my system is showing I am running 17.04(development branch).

```
$ lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Zesty Zapus (development branch)
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty
```

I don't think I had allowed system to upgrade to latest pre-release version.
Ubuntu's software and updates won't open either.
Here:

```
$ software-properties-gtk
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Ubuntu/zesty
```

System's sources.list show that packages are installed from *yakkety* repositories.

```
# deb cdrom:[Xubuntu 16.10 _Yakkety Yak_ - Release amd64 (20161012.2)]/ yakkety main multiverse restricted universe

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu yakkety partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu yakkety partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security multiverse
```

Anyone who could help me resolve this? I do not understand why my system is showing 17.04 though I installed 16.10.

Referring to 
[My computer says i am running ubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858199/my-computer-says-i-am-running-ubuntu-17-04), Here is the output from

`apt-cache policy base-files`:

```
base-files:
  Installed: 9.6ubuntu6
  Candidate: 9.6ubuntu6
  Version table:
 *** 9.6ubuntu6 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     9.6ubuntu5 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Solve what? What's the goal now?

Comment: I am unable to understand whether I am running 17.04 or 16.10? Because lsb_release says 17.04 but sources.list shows 16.10 package repos.

Comment: I tried compiling the 17.04 kernel on my machine to see if that would make it more stable, and that seemed to not start my desktop environment (but show boot console). of course I have other kernel builds so I'm fine, but there are some quirks like the update manager crashes on boot so I can't change anything. So it seems I'm stuck like this unless I reinstall