# difficulty upgrading distribution from yakkety/zesty

Tags: upgrade, 17.10, 17.04, ppa, 16.10

I'm trying to upgrade my Ubuntu distribution to version 17.10 Artful Aardvark from my current version, which is either 17.04 Zesty Zapus or 16.10 Yakkety Yak.

Ok, so I start out with the standard

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

I encounter multiple PPA errors (`Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu yakkety Release 404 Not Found` and the like).

It asks if I want to rewrite my `sources.list` in order to update `zesty` entries to `artful`. I say yes. It then says no valid entries for `zesty` are found and asks if it should add default entries for `artful`. I say yes. It disables third-party sources.

It appears to do an `apt update` and then halts saying

```
Error during update

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of network problem, please check your network connection and retry.
```

There is no network problem.

It goes on in its error message to mention how some repositories do not have a Release file, though it doesn't indicate that this is a major problem.

Then, it halts, saying only

```
Restoring original system state
```

To try to address what seems to be problems arising from third-party sources, I  try to remove them, starting with running a `sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes` I encounter an error that ends with the following:

```
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Ubuntu/zesty
```

So, now I don't know what to do. The error messages don't make sense to me and I've seen references both to yakkety and zesty.

I ran `lsb_release -a` and it returns the following:

```
No LSB modules are available
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Zesty Zapus (development branch)
Release:        17.04
Codename:       zesty
```

When I do `egrep -v '^#|^ *$' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` I see many references to yakkety and no references to zesty.

Can anyone guess at what might be wrong and how I might advance out of this mess?

---

EDIT: A suggestion from @pomsky prompted me to modify `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

First, I changed the sources to old-releases.ubuntu.com. With this the problems continued. Second, I changed all `yakkety` references to `zesty` references. This seemed to make things work.

The `do-release-upgrade` then ran as expected and apparently successfully and the references in `sources.list` changed from `zesty` to `artful`.

Comment: Related (but unanswered): https://askubuntu.com/questions/866052/lsb-release-in-xubuntu-showing-17-04-zesty-zapus-development-branch

Comment: Have you tried this https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release?

Comment: @pomsky Thanks for that suggestion. The solution there didn't work, but prompted me to change distribution name references in `sources.list` manually and this seems to have made things work. I've edited my question accordingly.